# How do I make my line of code into a function (def main)

Tags: python

How do I make my line of code into a function (def main) so it returns at the end and you can input user weight again if there was an invalid input? I'm new and can't seem to figure it out

```
#Determine your weight in kg
pounds = int(input("Enter weight in Pounds: "))
kgs = pounds/2.2046

print("The weight in kgs is",round(kgs))

#Input convert weight (lbs -> kgs)
Weight = float(input("Enter your weight on Earth in kg: "))

if Weight <= 0:
    print("Your weight must be positive.")
else:
    print("Weight on Mercury is", Weight*0.38, "kg.")
    print("Weight on Venus is", Weight*0.91, "kg.")
    print("Weight on Mars is", Weight*0.38, "kg.")
    print("Weight on Jupiter is", Weight*2.34, "kg.")
    print("Weight on Saturn is", Weight*1.06, "kg.")
    print("Weight on Uranus is", Weight*0.92, "kg.")
    print("Weight on Neptune is", Weight*1.19, "kg.")
    print("Weight on Pluto is", Weight*0.06, "kg.")
```

Comment: This site is not a substitute for basic tutorials and Google searches. Just look up any guide ever on how functions in Python work, and how you can call them and return things from them, and use the returned value. What do you need our help for that searching entire internet wasn't able to solve?

Comment: Use a while loop to keep prompting an input and only exit the loop if the input is a positive number

Comment: I think this is a valid question. Reading tutorials can't help to determine where a function can be used when refactoring and is a valid case for help.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the behavior you want is actually something like the result of the following script.

```
conversions = [
 ("Mercury", 0.38),
 ("Venus",   0.91),
 ("Mars",    0.38),
 ("Jupter",  2.34),
 ("Saturn",  1.06),
 ("Uranus",  0.92),
 ("Neptune", 1.19),
 ("Pluto",   0.06)]

#Determine your weight in kg
pounds = int(input("Enter weight in Pounds: "))
kgs = pounds/2.2046

print("The weight in kgs is",round(kgs))

#Input convert weight (lbs -> kgs)
while True:
    Weight = float(input("Enter your weight on Earth in kg: "))
    if Weight > 0:
        break
    else:
        print("Your weight must be positive.")

for planet, factor in conversions:
    print(f"Weight on {planet} is {Weight*factor:.2f} kg.")
```

Comment: Why ask for the weight in kg when it's already known? Wouldn't it be better to move the pound input into your loop and condition break on that and remove the kg input?

Comment: Good question, ask OP. It sounds to me like the only change in behavior that's desired is that the program keeps asking for a weight until a valid weight is entered.

Comment: Ah, true. Sorry, you were just using what he had. I generally just clean things like this up when I answer.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? Entering 0 will end the loop.

```
def weight_on_planet(planet, weight):
    if planet == "Mercury":
        return weight*0.38
    elif planet == "Venus":
        return weight*0.91
    elif planet == "Mars":
        return weight*0.38
    elif planet == "Jupiter":
        return weight*2.34
    elif planet == "Saturn":
        return weight*1.06
    elif planet == "Uranus":
        return weight*0.92
    elif planet == "Neptune":
        return weight*1.19
    elif planet == "Pluto":
        return weight*0.06
    else:
        return "Invalid planet"

def main():
    weight = float(input("Enter weight on Earth in pounds: "))
    if(weight == 0):
        exit()
    kgs = weight/2.2046
    print("The weight in kgs is",round(kgs))
    planet = input("Enter a planet to see how much you weigh there: ")
    planet_weight = weight_on_planet(planet, weight)
    print("Weight on {0} is {1:.1f}".format(planet, planet_weight))
    main()

main()
```

Output:

```
Enter weight on Earth in pounds: 100
The weight in kgs is 45
Enter a planet to see how much you weigh there: Mars
Weight on Mars is 38.0
Enter weight on Earth in pounds: 0
```